# Merge two dataframes if timestamp of x is within time interval of y

Tags: r, merge

I cannot get a solution to this problem. I have two dataframes. DF1  and DF2. I would like to merge the columns of DF2 to DF1 if the timestamp in DF1 is within the time interval specified in DF2.
Here is an example of the two dataframes:

```
DF1 <- structure(list(Airspeed = c(582L, 478L, 524L), Outbound.Track = c(119L, 78L,134L), Rem.Ground.Dist = c(369L, 119L, 196L), Timestamp=structure(c(1451636817.52577, 1451638203.76569, 1451637753.43511),class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "")), .Names =c("Airspeed", "Outbound.Track","Rem.Ground.Dist", "Timestamp"), row.names =c(1L, 12L, 7L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))

DF2 <- structure(list(Temperature = c(-18.5, -60, -35), Wind_Direction = c("324", "335", "313"), Wind_Speed = c("032", "041", "056"), onebef =structure(c(1451629620, 1451634660, 1451637000), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), oneaft = structure(c(1451636820, 1451641860, 1451644200), class =c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"))), .Names = c("Temperature", "Wind_Direction", "Wind_Speed","onebef", "oneaft"), row.names = c(1358L, 1654L, 2068L), class = "data.frame")

head(DF1)
head(DF2)
```

I want to merge DF1 with DF2. So if there is a match (timestamp of DF1 is within time interval of any DF2), the values of DF2 (Wind_Speed, Wind_Direction, Temperature) should be added to DF1.

Two Problems I am facing:

1. How to do the match/merge? My dataframe is quite large (7000 rows in DF1 and DF2)
2. How to ensure that rows of DF1 are duplicated if there are several matches?

I am looking forward to your help!Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use sqldf:

```
library(sqldf)
df<-sqldf('select d1.*,d2.*
           from DF1 d1
           left join DF2 d2
             on d1.Timestamp >= d2.onebef
               AND d1.Timestamp <= d2.oneaft
          ')
df
```

Comment: or `... on d1.Timestamp between d2.onebef and d2.oneaft`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `merge()` with the `all = TRUE` option to combine all rows of `DF1` with all rows from `DF2`. Then you can check your condition:

```
x <- merge(DF1, DF2, all = TRUE)

x[x$Timestamp >= x$onebef & x$Timestamp <= x$oneaft,]

  Airspeed Outbound.Track Rem.Ground.Dist           Timestamp Temperature Wind_Direction Wind_Speed              onebef
1      582            119             369 2016-01-01 09:26:57       -18.5            324        032 2016-01-01 07:27:00
4      582            119             369 2016-01-01 09:26:57       -60.0            335        041 2016-01-01 08:51:00
5      478             78             119 2016-01-01 09:50:03       -60.0            335        041 2016-01-01 08:51:00
6      524            134             196 2016-01-01 09:42:33       -60.0            335        041 2016-01-01 08:51:00
8      478             78             119 2016-01-01 09:50:03       -35.0            313        056 2016-01-01 09:30:00
9      524            134             196 2016-01-01 09:42:33       -35.0            313        056 2016-01-01 09:30:00
           oneaft
1 2016-01-01 09:27:00
4 2016-01-01 10:51:00
5 2016-01-01 10:51:00
6 2016-01-01 10:51:00
8 2016-01-01 11:30:00
9 2016-01-01 11:30:00
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work fine with your example, but you might struggle with the real datasets as it will create a very big dataset (combine each row of DF1 with DF2) before it keeps the relevant rows.

Give it a try and see how it works.

```
library(dplyr)

DF1 <- structure(list(Airspeed = c(582L, 478L, 524L), Outbound.Track = c(119L, 78L,134L), Rem.Ground.Dist = c(369L, 119L, 196L), Timestamp=structure(c(1451636817.52577, 1451638203.76569, 1451637753.43511),class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "")), .Names =c("Airspeed", "Outbound.Track","Rem.Ground.Dist", "Timestamp"), row.names =c(1L, 12L, 7L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))

DF2 <- structure(list(Temperature = c(-18.5, -60, -35), Wind_Direction = c("324", "335", "313"), Wind_Speed = c("032", "041", "056"), onebef =structure(c(1451629620, 1451634660, 1451637000), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), oneaft = structure(c(1451636820, 1451641860, 1451644200), class =c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"))), .Names = c("Temperature", "Wind_Direction", "Wind_Speed","onebef", "oneaft"), row.names = c(1358L, 1654L, 2068L), class = "data.frame")


merge(DF1, DF2) %>%                                  # combine every row of DF1 with DF2
  filter(onebef <= Timestamp & Timestamp <= oneaft)  # keep rows where Timestampe is between the interval


#   Airspeed Outbound.Track Rem.Ground.Dist           Timestamp Temperature Wind_Direction Wind_Speed              onebef              oneaft
# 1      582            119             369 2016-01-01 08:26:57       -18.5            324        032 2016-01-01 06:27:00 2016-01-01 08:27:00
# 2      582            119             369 2016-01-01 08:26:57       -60.0            335        041 2016-01-01 07:51:00 2016-01-01 09:51:00
# 3      478             78             119 2016-01-01 08:50:03       -60.0            335        041 2016-01-01 07:51:00 2016-01-01 09:51:00
# 4      524            134             196 2016-01-01 08:42:33       -60.0            335        041 2016-01-01 07:51:00 2016-01-01 09:51:00
# 5      478             78             119 2016-01-01 08:50:03       -35.0            313        056 2016-01-01 08:30:00 2016-01-01 10:30:00
# 6      524            134             196 2016-01-01 08:42:33       -35.0            313        056 2016-01-01 08:30:00 2016-01-01 10:30:00
```

Comment: Unfortuantely I get the error of differening number of rows. Any way to work around that error?

Comment: In which step do you get that error? Is it on the real datasets or on the example?

Comment: Then probably the real dataset doesn't match the example dataset exactly. Most likely some rows are missing some column values.

Comment: I changed the `rowwise` part with `merge` (like @ottlngr) which is simpler and does the same thing. Not sure if this will solve your issue.