# Combine two datasets with Interval time condition in R (I would like to avoid combinations and just have unique matches)

Tags: r, datatable, dplyr, lubridate

I have two separate datasets: df1 and df2. I would like to create a new dataset, df3 that would match the endtime column of df1 with the sent column of df2 if the datetimes are within 20 seconds of each other.

```
 df1

 endtime                     ID

 1/7/2020  1:35:08 AM         A
 1/7/2020  1:39:00 AM         B
 1/20/2020 1:45:00 AM         C



 df2

sent                         ID

1/7/2020  1:35:20 AM          E
1/7/2020  1:42:00 AM          F
1/20/2020 1:55:00 AM          G
1/20/2020 2:00:00 AM          E
```

This is my desired output for df3. There is only one row, because there are only two values that match the condition of being within 20 seconds of the endtime and sent columns. I would like unique matches, not a combination. Essentially a merge with a time condition.

```
endtime                  sent 

1/7/2020 1:35:08 AM      1/7/2020  1:35:20 AM
```

Here is the dput:

```
df1

structure(list(endtime = structure(c(2L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("1/10/2020 1:45:00 AM", 
"1/7/2020 1:35:08 AM", "1/7/2020 1:39:00 AM"), class = "factor"), 
ID = structure(1:3, .Label = c("A", "B", "C"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names =   c(NA, 
 -3L))





 df2

 structure(list(sent = structure(c(3L, 4L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("1/20/2020 1:55:00 AM", 
 "1/20/2020 2:00:00 AM", "1/7/2020 1:35:20 AM", "1/7/2020 1:42:00 AM"
 ), class = "factor"), ID = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("E", 
"F", "G"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

This is what I have tried:

I am thinking of performing a left join and matching the values, or I can use merge(), but the tricky part is matching the values with the conditional statement. Any suggestion is appreciated.

```
library(dplyr)
left_join(df1, df2)
```

Comment: How many rows are there? I am asking because one way to do this would be to  merge **every** row from `df1`  with **every** row from `df2` and then remove all rows where the condition doesn't hold... O

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Merge two dataframes if timestamp of x is within time interval of y](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42507882/merge-two-dataframes-if-timestamp-of-x-is-within-time-interval-of-y)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be, we need to do a `crossing` and then `filter` after converting to `DateTime` class

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(lubridate)
crossing(endtime = as.POSIXct(df1$endtime,format ="%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p" ), 
           sent = as.POSIXct(df2$sent, format = "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")) %>% 
     filter((endtime - seconds(20)) <= sent, 
                 (endtime + seconds(20)) >= (sent)) %>%
     mutate_all(format, format = "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p") %>%
     distinct
# A tibble: 1 x 2
#  endtime                sent                  
#  <chr>                  <chr>                 
#1 01/07/2020 01:35:08 AM 01/07/2020 01:35:20 AM
```

Comment: Ok thank you Akrun, will this exclude any duplicates?

Comment: @TanishaHudson You can add `%>% distinct` at the end

Comment: ok Its just, I am getting duplicate values in the sent row because more than one endtime match with the same sent value

Comment: @TanishaHudson The `crossing` does full expansion for each value of 'endtime' with that of 'sent'.  If you need to get the distinct by a particular coumn use `distinct(sent, .keep_all = TRUE)`

Comment: Hello @akrun, how can I see the remaining values? Like an anti join?

Comment: @TanishaHudson Yes if you have created an object then doing `anti_join` with the orignal data can get the other rows